# Why aren't any new accounts I create have their password going into my membership database as encrypted?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create new accounts and have the signup details for each user enter into my membership database as encrypted - at the moment the actual password can be seen in the database. Why is this? I am using the form validation library and have included the md5 rule for the password field but it doesnt seem to have made a difference.

Controller:

```
 function register()
 {

$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

$this->load->library('form_validation');


$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_usernameTaken|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');


$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');


if ( $this->form_validation->run()&& !$this->membership->usernameTaken($username)){

$this->membership->newUser($username, $password);
$this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
$this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
redirect('home');
 }


else 
   {

    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'NOT_OK');
    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('account/signuptitle');
    $this->load->view('account/signupview');
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');

  }

 }
```

Thanks again for the help

Model:

```
 function newUser($username, $password)
{
    $newMember = array ('username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password);
    $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $newMember);

}



function usernameTaken($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from ('membership')->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "<p>";
        echo 'username taken';
        echo "</p>";
        return true;
    }

   else{

    return false;

   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `$username` and `$password` before running the validation. `set_rules` method just sets the rules for validation. It doesn't run it. They are validated at `$this->form_validation->run()` method. So just place those assignment statements inside `if` block.

It is better to use `trim` first in `set_rules` method. i have used it as first rule. You are already checking `callback_usernameTaken` in set_rules method so no need to check it again in if statement. `usernameTaken` is better to be in controller than in model. so moved it there. And finally check out the changes i made to usernameTaken method. I have added `$this->form_validation->set_message` method call and interchanged `true` and `false`.

```
function register()
{

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|callback_usernameTaken|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5');

    if ( $this->form_validation->run() ){

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->membership->newUser($username, $password);
        $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
        redirect('home');
    }
    else {

        $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'NOT_OK');
        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('account/signuptitle');
        $this->load->view('account/signupview');
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');
    }
}

function usernameTaken($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from ('membership')->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('usernameTaken', 'username taken');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
   }
}
```

CodeIgniter's form-validation class provides both form validation and data prepping features. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html
So there is nothing wrong in using `md5` in `set_rules` method. It will run `md5` method and return the encrypted string.

And for better encryption use `Mcrypt` extension: php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php or `crypt` function: php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php.

Comment: Do you mean put this in the if statement? - $username = $this->input->post('username');
   $password = $this->input->post('password');

Comment: Yes. Try it and let us know if it is worked.

Comment: And for better encryption use `Mcrypt` extension: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php or `crypt` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php.

Comment: I tried this but now I get Message: Undefined variable: username. This is because I dont want an already taken username going into the database. Please see the if statement - I have removed the ! from it in an effort for the function usernameTaken will be taken into account. Please see my updated code for my model function.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It is better to use `trim` first in set_rules method. i have used it as first rule. You are already checking `callback_usernameTaken` in set_rules method so no need to check it again in if statement. `usernameTaken` is better to be in controller than in model. so moved it there. And finally check out the changes i made to `usernameTaken` method. I have added `$this->form_validation->set_message` method call and interchanged `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 2):

The form validation rules validate the form values, it does not change them so if you want to encrypt your password, you would have to do that after the form has passed validation / before you add it to the database.

Apart from that `md5` is not a very good way to encrypt your password and it does not return a boolean value (`true` or `false`), it returns a string which will always evaluate to `true` so it is of no use in the validation function.

Comment: so what alternative would you suggest?

Comment: @Frank_g bcrypt probably, depending on what is available, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords